# I am trying to store my node rest api data to mongodb atlas. But getting insertion errors

Tags: mongodb, rest, mern, reactjs

I am trying to register the user  to mongodb atlas for registration and login but i am geting an error 404.

here is full link to mycode

https://github.com/badrinathareddyr/falcon.git

server.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const authRoute = require('../backend/routes/auth')

//connect to database
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });
mongoose.connect(
    process.env[DB_CONNECT], { useNewUrlParser: true }, () =>
    console.log('connected to db!')
);

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());

//middlewareroutes
app.use('/register', authRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server up and running'));
```

auth.js file

```js
var express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Please pass email and password.' });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        // save the user
        newUser.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Email already exists.' });
            }
            res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.' });
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code in the question, so this question can help future visitors after you change your repository.

Comment: Please add what have you tried till now and what you are not able to figure out? A code snippet or the process you followed to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `process.env.DB_CONNECT` in your code is undefined. Change line 5 of your `src/backend/server.js` file like below:

`const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });`
then comment `dotenv.config()`

and copy `.env` to `src/backend/`.

Or change line 10 or the file like this:

`dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });`

You have `const User = require('../models/User');` two time in `backend/routes/auth.js`. Comment line 9. It will give you error.

I fixed it and created pull request in github. Merge it.